# meaning of: "necessity does not freedom make"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of this sentence:
"necessity does not freedom make"

in

Freedom is possible only in society, not outside of it.
But necessity does not freedom make. Rousseau’s promises notwithstanding – that we would be as free “as before” – counterfactual comparisons are irrelevant.

Comment: Where did you find this passage? The context given doesn't illuminate much. And the writing seems unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @Bradd Szonye See [here](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/chapter.jsf?bid=CBO9780511778490&cid=CBO9780511778490A041)  and  [here](http://tinyurl.com/mv8fml5)

Answer (score 1):

In the Adam Przeworski book this is excerpted from, [Democracy and the Limits of Self-Government](http://tinyurl.com/mv8fml5the), the first sentence you quote ends this paragraph:

> Autonomy is a particular kind of liberty – the freedom to live under
>   laws one wants to live under given that living under laws one must.
>   ***The argument, from Rousseau to Kelsen, has been that because to live
>   together we must live under laws, this is the only kind of freedom
>   possible.*** Liberty cannot mean freedom in the state of nature. Legal
>   order enables actions that are not feasible in the state of nature: In
>   the latter each individual is exposed to aggression or exploitation by
>   others, so that no one is free from interference. Freedom is possible
>   only in society, not outside of it.

"But necessity does not freedom make," begins the next paragraph.

So, apparently the "necessity" that "does not freedom make" (or "does not make freedom"), in this case, is the necessity of living under laws so that we can coexist. Przeworski seems to be saying that he disagrees with writers, "from Rousseau to Kelsen," who argue that "because to live together we must live under laws, this is the only kind of freedom possible." Perhaps, he seems to argue, this is no freedom at all.

Then again, perhaps I misunderstand his point. As Bradd Szonye noted above, this is some deeply cumbersome prose. Not being sure of my interpretation, I would make this a comment rather than an answer, but it's too long for that.